# highlight a specific word using jspdf

Tags: angularjs, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

how can I highlight a specific word in a line using jspdf

```
autoTable(doc, {
    alternateRowStyles: {fillColor : '#ffffff'},
    bodyStyles:{font:'times'},
    styles:{lineColor:'#000000',lineWidth:0.1},
    
    body:[['Loan Application No.',''],
          ['Date',''],
          ['Borrower’s Name, Address & Mobile Number:',''],
          ['E Mail ID',Email],
  ]       
  });
```

Here, i need to highlight just Borrower's Name and expected output of 3rd cell is like .. **Borrower’s Name**, Address & Mobile Number: